# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseObject

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform

This is my code to request the sendCode which is to be received by sms. When the number is enter and submitted it crashes and I still do receive the code by sms.

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendCode", params, new FunctionCallback<JSONObject>() {
                    public void done(JSONObject response, ParseException e) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("Cloud Response", "There were no exceptions! " + response.toString());
                            codeUI();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Cloud Response", "Exception: " + response.toString() + e);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Something went wrong.  Please try again." + e,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            phoneNumberUI();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This is my JSON file on the Parse Cloud

```
if (!phoneNumber || (phoneNumber.length != 10 && phoneNumber.length != 11)) return res.error('Invalid Parameters');
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo('username', phoneNumber + "");
    query.first().then(function(result) {
        var min = 1000; var max = 9999;
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

        if (result) {
            result.setPassword(secretPasswordToken + num);
            result.set("language", language);
            result.save().then(function() {
                return sendCodeSms(phoneNumber, num, language);
            }).then(function() {
                res.success({});
            }, function(err) {
                res.error(err);
            });
```

Comment: The application crashes during requesting the code by sms. After the app is crashed I do get the code by sms.

Comment: please provide the complete stacktrace. I know You posted it at the question, but this must not be the cause of the exception. So it is necessary to see the full logcat output..

Answer (score 0):

The ParseCloud function returns a HashMap hierarchy based on your javascript so you can have your code like the following.

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendCode", params, new FunctionCallback<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
    public void done(HashMap<String, Object> response, ParseException e) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("Cloud Response", "There were no exceptions! " + response.toString());
            Log.d("Cloud Response", response.get("data").toString());
            codeUI();
        } else {
            Log.d("Cloud Response", "Exception: " + response.toString() + e);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.  Please try again." + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            phoneNumberUI();
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your javascript you can do for the response...

```
response.success({ data: "yay" });
```